# Запомнить значения из нескольких TextBox-ов отдельно для выбранного элемента CheckListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как в c# vs2010 решить следующую задачу.

Я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде табеля рабочего времени, для этого на форме есть `CheckListBox1`, в который при открытии формы загружаются несколько фамилий. А также на форме есть 31 шт `TextBox`-ов (`TextBox1` - `TextBox31`).

С помощью определенных кнопок в `TextBox`-сы заносятся данные.

Вопрос: Как запомнить "в память" данные из `TextBox`-сов отдельно для каждого выделенного элемента в `CheckListBox1`, другими словами, выделяем строку 1 в `CheckListBox1` - заполняем данных `TextBox`-ов, выделяем строку 2 в `CheckListBox1` - заполняем данные `TextBox`-ов для другой фамилии и т.д.?

Причем при переключении в `CheckListBox1` обратно в любой последовательности, например, на строку1 со строки 2, показать данные `TextBox`-ов ранее заполненные для этой строки 1. И хранить и подгружать значения в `TextBox`-ы при выборе(смене) пункта в `CheckListBox1` динамически, пока не нажать кнопку, например, Сохранить в текстовый файл?

Прикладываю скрин формы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала классический вопрос в плохооформленных вопросах: wpf или winforms?

Comment: Извините, winforms!

Answer (score 2):

Большинство задач можно решить множеством способов. Предложенный мной - лишь один из многих.

Создадим класс-сущность, описывающий человека. Он содержит имя (можно добавить дополнительные свойства по желанию) и по одному свойству на каждый день месяца. Громоздко, зато позволяет легко и просто делать data binding - привязку данных.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    // ...
    // всего 31 свойство, по количеству дней
}
```

Создадим коллекцию, в которой будут храниться сотрудники вашего табеля. Это будет поле формы.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
```

Добавляем в неё всех работников:

```
persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Вася" });
persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Маша" });
```

Привязываем нашу коллекцию к компоненту:

```
var listBox = ((ListBox)checkedListBox1);
listBox.DataSource = persons;
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Также делаем привязку текстбоксов к нашей коллекции:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value1");
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value2");
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value3");
// итого 31 штука
```

Это второй громоздкий кусок кода, но его в принципе можно заменить циклом.

Всё! Теперь данные введённые в текстбоксы будут автоматически заноситься в свойства человека. При выделении сотрудника в `CheckedListBox` именно его данные будут появляться в табеле.

---

Сохранение данных в файл делается элементарно с помощью сериализации. Например, используем библиотеку Json.NET (подключите к проекту из nuget).

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
File.WriteAllText("data.txt", json);
```

Чтение из файла также просто:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Отмечу лишь, что привязку данных нужно делать после чтения. Если она уже была сделана, то нужно удалить старую привязку.

```
var listBox = ((ListBox)checkedListBox1);
listBox.DataSource = persons;
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
textBox2.DataBindings.Clear();
textBox3.DataBindings.Clear();
// и т. д.

textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value1");
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value2");
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value3");
// и т. д.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, переключение строк в CheckListBox с отображением данных TextBox-ов получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему появляется ошибка "Элемент "persons" не существует в текущем контексте" в коде сохранения в текстовый файл: private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons); File.WriteAllText("data.txt", json); }. Я скачала и добавила ссылкой к проекту файл "Newtonsoft.Json.dll", прописала "using Newtonsoft.Json;"

Comment: @ольгаг - Скорее всего `persons` у вас сделано локальной переменной. Сделайте его полем класса (формы).

Comment: Да было локальной переменной, сохранение получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает чтение из этого сохраненного файла: private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
            persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
        }. По нажатию кнопки, CheckListBox и TextBox-ы остаются пустыми? Т.е. запускаю форму, нажимаю кнопку btn2 и пусто.

Comment: @ольгаг - после чтения нужно сделать повторную привязку данных.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить задачу с подсчетами: сейчас у меня код выполняет расчет по "таймеру" -- как только введены данные в TextBox-ы (31шт), то сразу по определенному алгоритму они суммируются в другие итоговые TextBox-ы. Как значения из итоговых TextBox-сов запоминать и подсчитывать по таймеру для каждого работника при смене в CheckBox?

Comment: @ольгаг - не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Создайте новую тему с этим вопросом. Хотя, полагаю, можно добавить в класс `Person` свойства для итоговых значений и также привязать их к итоговым текстбоксам.

Comment: Спасибо! Привязала итоговые текстбоксы по аналогии и при переключении строки в CheckLIstBox запускаю событие таймера.